# How remove text before "," (include) in every lines?

Tags: regular-expressions, replace

suppose I has the next text:

```
-1,0x0 Fireplace HD
1160,0x0 Music HD
719,1 HD
-1,1 MUSIC CHANNEL
154,1+1
-1,100% News
-1,100AutoMoto TV
```

I need to remove text before "**,**" (include ,)

So the result must be like this:

```
0x0 Fireplace HD
0x0 Music HD
1 HD
1 MUSIC CHANNEL
1+1
100% News
100AutoMoto TV
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `query-replace-regexp`, which is bound to `C-M-%` by default.

In this case you want to replace everything from the beginning of the line to the last ',':

```
^.*,
```

with nothing.

Comment: I use regexp   .*,